# how to use shell script checking last changed time of a file

Tags: file, datetime, shell, copy

I want to find if certain files are changed within the last three minutes in order to decide if the `cp` was successful, and if I should `exit` or continue the script. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get the last modification time of a file with `stat`, and the current date with `date`. You can use format strings for both to get them in "seconds since the epoch":

```
current=`date +%s`
last_modified=`stat -c "%Y" $file`
```

Then, it's pretty easy to put that in a condition. For example:

```
if [ $(($current-$last_modified)) -gt 180 ]; then 
     echo "old"; 
else 
     echo "new"; 
fi
```

Comment: How widely supported is `stat -c %Y`? On OS X I would use `stat -f %m`, but on some Linux flavours `stat -f` displays filesystem information. Most systems support `date -r "$file" +%s`, but to be awkward that doesn't work on OS X… fun stuff :)

Comment: What is 180 in the "if condition"? Is it in seconds or days?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of this if statement depends on your particular shell, but the date commands don't. I use bash; modify as necessary.

```
if [ $(( $(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r <file>) )) -le 180 ]; then
    # was modified in last three minutes
else
    # was not modified in last three minutes
fi
```

The `+%s` tells date to output a UNIX time (the important bit is that it's an integer in seconds).  You can also use stat to get this information - the command `stat -c %Y <file>` is equivalent.  Make sure to use `%Y` not `%y`, so that you get a usable time in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

The stat command will give you the last modification time

```
stat -c %y <filename>
```

Answer (score 3):

Find can output the file name if it has been modified in the last 3 minutes.

```
find file1 -maxdepth 0 -mmin -3
```

Comment: If you want to add that as a test in your script, you can use: `if [ -n "$(find etc...)" ]; then...`

Answer (score 0):

A file timestamp change does not really imply you successfully copied.
If you land up corrupting the file or the file-system runs out of space,
you will probably still see a timestamp change (need to confirm that).

I do not get the exact context of your requirement.
If you fire a `cp`, it completes and returns -- does not return while it is working.
So, isn't the return (with success exit code) a good indicator of success?

How and why would you exit partly within a `cp` operation?
Or, is that a batch `cp` script that loops over the list of files...
some elaboration would help.

Comment: the cp is done in one script and the verifying is done in another script. so exist will not stop cp in the middle. by the way, how can I get the verify the exist code of cp? thank you